# Are Cloud Firestore queries still case sensitive?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase Realtime Database accept queries with strings in case sensitive manner.

Does this still apply for Firestore?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, queries are still case sensitive.

To support case-insensitive or any other canonicalization you'll need to write a separate field that contains the canonicalized version and query against that. For example

```
db.collection("users").where("name", "==", "Dan")
db.collection("users").where("name_lowercase", "==", "dan")
```

Also see my longer answer here: [Cloud Firestore Case Insensitive Sorting Using Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096063/cloud-firestore-case-insensitive-sorting-using-query/48098215#48098215)

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: That is very bad still in 2019 :/

Comment: Can't believe this is still an issue :/

Comment: Same issue in 2021

Comment: OMG, when will it be available to add support of query with or without case sensitivity in Firestore API?

Comment: Guys, still in after pandemic 2022

Comment: So this is still a thing? I cannot order alphabetically regardless of case?

Comment: Is this still not solved?

Comment: damn so simple yet firebase can't fix it

Comment: Whoever wrote Firebase firestore, sucks.. and don't get me started on realtime database.