# How to change text field error label when an existing user is found in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example on submission of a form containing Text Form Fields using validation and text editing controllers, how can I change the error label to show that an user with the username entered already exists after checking the database?

Sample Code:

[image: Sample Code]

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output:]

Comment: it seems duplicated question. Please check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194662/flutter-async-validator-of-textformfield

Comment: I will try it out and let you know! Thank you.

Comment: Always copy-paste your actual code on StackOverflow instead of adding screenshots.