# Asynchronous validation with Flutter Form

Tags: flutter

I'm new in Flutter. In my app I need option for checking username already exist or not asynchronously from database when user typed and focus out from text box.

The `validator` require `String` return type that's why I can not add `Future<String>`

How can I do like as below with Flutter `TextFormField`? or any process that full fill my requirement.

```
validator: myValidator
```

```
Future myValidator(String username) async{
    return await checkUser(username);
}
```

Comment: Check my answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75685423/11217849). Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** Currently Flutter doesn't support the async function in `validator`. You can do it in a tricky way.

Define these variables

```dart
dynamic _validationMsg;
final _usernameCtrl = TextEditingController();
```

Your async validator function (with modification)

```dart
Future myValidator(String username) async{
    _validationMsg = null;
    setState(() {});

    bool isExist = await checkUser(username);
    
    if(isExist){
      _validationMsg = "${username} already taken";
      setState(() {});
    }
}
```

Now add the `TextFormField` widget wrapped with a `Focus` widget.

```dart
Focus(
  child: TextFormField(
    controller: _usernameCtrl,
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
    validator: (val) => _validationMsg,
  ),
  onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
    if (!hasFocus) myValidator(_usernameCtrl.text);
  }
)
```

Code Ref: https://flutter-tutorial.com/flutter-async-validation

Answer (score -3):

Can you try something like this:

```
validator: (username) async {
  String result = await checkUser(username);
  return result;  
}
```

Comment: `validator` not take async callback.