# Still problems with async validations in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I like to check if an email already exists in the database on my backend. Therefore I tried to use a state var which should be changed after the async call returns. I found the following threads which contains accepted answeres.

[Flutter - Async Validator of TextFormField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194662/flutter-async-validator-of-textformfield)

[Flutter firebase validation of form field inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584520/flutter-firebase-validation-of-form-field-inputs?rq=1)

I tried these answeres and also some variations but it still doesn't work for me. I just simulate the backend call. Setting _emailExist to true is printed but I don't see any error. If I click the button twice, the error message is shown correctly.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _loginFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool _emailExist = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  checkEmail(String name) {

    // Simulare async call
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((val) {
      setState(() {
        _emailExist = true;
      });
      print(_emailExist);
    });
    return _emailExist;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Test"),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Form(
          key: _loginFormKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                validator: (value) =>
                checkEmail(value) ? "Email already taken" : null,
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Login"),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_loginFormKey.currentState.validate()) {}
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextFormField` expects a synchronous function as a validator (that's an ordinary function that does some task and then *returns* its result).

`checkEmail` is exactly this, a synchronous function. It sets up a `Future` which will, in two seconds, set `_emailExist` to `true`. But crucially, it doesn't then wait around for two seconds. It immediately *returns* the current value of `_emailExist` (which is `false` the first time it runs). Two seconds later, your `Future` resolves and sets `_emailExist` to true. That's why, when you run it the second time, it works as expected (`_checkEmail` again returns the current value of `_emailExist` but this is now `true`).

One way around this is to provide `onChanged` and `decoration` arguments to achieve the same effect:

```
TextFormField(
  onChanged: _handleChange,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    errorText: _emailExist ? "Email already taken" : null,
  ),
),
```

Now, you can make your asynchronous backend call as the text field changes, and then update state depending on the response:

```
void _handleChange(String val) {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then(() {
    setState(() {
      _emailExist = true;
    });
    print(_emailExist);
  });
}
```

It's a good idea to [debounce](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) this function so you're not sending off a request with every letter the user types!

Here's a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY) and some [docs](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) on asynchronous coding in Flutter/Dart.