# How can I check if value exists in Firebase using Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database in firebase with a structure like this:

```
Collection("Users").Document("user.uid").Collection("chats")
```

Im using a texfield --> onSubmit to create new data when I press enter key,

```
child: TextField(
decoration: InputDecoration(
 border: InputBorder.none,
hintText: 'Type your message...',
hintStyle: TextStyle(
 color: Colors.grey[500]),
),
 controller: queryController,
textInputAction:
  TextInputAction.send,
 onSubmitted: (msg) {},
}
```

I want to compare the entries of the TextField ( using a controller for example) with this key:

[Firebase information that I want to comare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qiumj.png)

Something like:

```
If (Controller== Databasekey) {
print("dont do it");
}
```

Does any way to do it?

Comment: Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122211/check-if-field-already-exists-in-flutter-firestore)