# How do I make toLowerCase() and toUpperCase() consistent across browsers

Tags: javascript, unicode, polyfills, unicode-normalization, case-folding

Are there JavaScript polyfill implementations of String.toLowerCase() and String.toUpperCase(), or other methods in JavaScript that can work with Unicode characters and are consistent across browsers?

### Background info

Performing the following will give difference results in browsers, or even between browser versions (E.g FireFox 54 vs 55):

```
document.write(String.fromCodePoint(223).normalize("NFKC").toLowerCase().toUpperCase().toLowerCase())
```

In Firefox 55 it gives you `ss`, in Firefox 54 it gives you `ß`.

Generally this is fine, and mechanisms such as Locales handle a lot of the cases you'd want; however, when you need consistent behavior across platforms such as talking to BaaS systems like [google-cloud-firestore](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore) it can greatly simplify interactions where you're essentially processing internal data on the client.

Comment: Have you tried the same with `toLocaleLowerCase()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase

Comment: This doesn't work because I need consistent behavior across browsers (all clients need the same result) and hence need it to be locale independent.

Comment: Why are you even converting to and fro?

Comment: To the close voters, this is definitely on-topic as a specific programming/algorithm question for JavaScript/Unicode as it pertains to different browser implementations.

Comment: Have you checked the changelog for FF55?

Comment: @connexo, I'm updating my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096063/cloud-firestore-case-insensitive-sorting-using-query to include details on unicode case folding as the current approach results in different data/results across clients. This isn't an issue in languages like Python/Java as you can ensure a consistent implementation, JavaScript in browsers is uniquely broken for this case. This issue is not specific to FF, but browsers in general - e.g. Chrome vs IE are different.

Comment: There have been changes as of ES6 regarding the handling of Unicode 16 characters, also reflecting in a change in the spec of how to implement `toLowerCase()`: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.tolowercase vs https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.16

Comment: Note that `String.fromCodePoint(223)` can be written as a string literal to simplify the example a bit: `'\xDF'`.

Comment: @MathiasBynens I was using fromCodePoint as I was cheating in my testing by passing data URL schemes to browsershots and it helped me avoid URL escaping that garbled the JavaScript. I know, terrible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this issue only seems to affect outdated versions of Firefox, so unless you explicitly need to support those old versions, you *could* choose to just not bother at all. The behavior for your example is the same in all modern browsers (since the change in Firefox). This can be verified [using jsvu + eshost](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsvu#integration-with-eshost-cli):

```
$ jsvu # Update installed JavaScript engine binaries to the latest version.

$ eshost -e '"\xDF".normalize("NFKC").toLowerCase().toUpperCase().toLowerCase()'
#### Chakra
ss

#### V8 --harmony
ss

#### JavaScriptCore
ss

#### V8
ss

#### SpiderMonkey
ss

#### xs
ss
```

But you asked how to solve this problem, so let’s continue.

Step 4 of https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.tolowercase states:

> Let `cuList` be a List where the elements are the result of `toLowercase(cpList)`, according to the Unicode Default Case Conversion algorithm.

This *Unicode Default Case Conversion algorithm* is specified in [section 3.13 Default Case Algorithms of the Unicode standard](https://unicode.org/versions/Unicode11.0.0/ch03.pdf).

> The full case mappings for Unicode characters are obtained by using the mappings from [`SpecialCasing.txt`](https://unicode.org/Public/11.0.0/ucd/SpecialCasing.txt) plus the mappings from [`UnicodeData.txt`](https://unicode.org/Public/11.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt), excluding any of the latter mappings that would conflict. Any character that does not have a mapping in these files is considered to map to itself.
>
> […]
>
> The following rules specify the default case conversion operations for Unicode strings. These rules use the full case conversion operations, `Uppercase_Mapping(C)`, `Lowercase_Mapping(C)`, and `Titlecase_Mapping(C)`, as well as the context-dependent mappings based on the casing context, as specified in Table 3-17.
>
> For a string `X`:
>
> - R1 `toUppercase(X)`: Map each character `C` in `X` to `Uppercase_Mapping(C)`.
> - R2 `toLowercase(X)`: Map each character `C` in `X` to `Lowercase_Mapping(C)`.

Here’s an example from [`SpecialCasing.txt`](https://unicode.org/Public/11.0.0/ucd/SpecialCasing.txt), with my annotation added below:

```
00DF  ; 00DF   ; 0053 0073; 0053 0053;                      # LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S
<code>; <lower>; <title>  ; <upper>  ; (<condition_list>;)? # <comment>
```

This line says that U+00DF (`'ß'`) lowercases to U+00DF (`ß`) and uppercases to U+0053 U+0053 (`SS`).

Here’s an example from [`UnicodeData.txt`](https://unicode.org/Public/11.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt), with my annotation added below:

```
0041  ; LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A; Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;; 0061   ;
<code>; <name>                ; <ignore>       ; <lower>; <upper>
```

This line says that U+0041 (`'A'`) lowercases to U+0061 (`'a'`). It doesn’t have an explicit uppercase mapping, meaning it uppercases to itself.

Here’s another example from [`UnicodeData.txt`](https://unicode.org/Public/11.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt):

```
0061  ; LATIN SMALL LETTER A; Ll;0;L;;;;;N;; ;0041;        ; 0041
<code>; <name>              ; <ignore>            ; <lower>; <upper>
```

This line says that U+0061 (`'a'`) uppercases to U+0041 (`'A'`). It doesn’t have an explicit lowercase mapping, meaning it lowercases to itself.

You could write a script that parses these two files, reads each line following these examples, and builds lowercase/uppercase mappings. You could then turn those mappings into a small JavaScript library that provides spec-compliant `toLowerCase`/`toUpperCase` functionality.

This seems like a lot of work. Depending on the old behavior in Firefox and what exactly changed (?) you could probably limit the work to *just* the special mappings in [`SpecialCasing.txt`](https://unicode.org/Public/11.0.0/ucd/SpecialCasing.txt). (I’m making this assumption that only the special casings changed in Firefox 55, based on the example you provided.)

```
// Instead of…
function normalize(string) {
  const normalized = string.normalize('NFKC');
  const lowercased = normalized.toLowerCase();
  return lowercased;
}

// …one could do something like:
function lowerCaseSpecialCases(string) {
  // TODO: replace all SpecialCasing.txt characters with their lowercase
  // mapping.
  return string.replace(/TODO/g, fn);
}
function normalize(string) {
  const normalized = string.normalize('NFKC');
  const fixed = lowerCaseSpecialCases(normalized); // Workaround for old Firefox 54 behavior.
  const lowercased = fixed.toLowerCase();
  return lowercased;
}
```

I wrote a script that parses `SpecialCasing.txt` and generates a JS library that implements the `lowerCaseSpecialCases` functionality mentioned above (as `toLower`) as well as `toUpper`. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/a37e3f3138069729aa434ea90eea4a3c Depending on your exact use case, you might not need the `toUpper` and its corresponding regex and map at all. Here’s the full generated library:

```
const reToLower = /[\u0130\u1F88-\u1F8F\u1F98-\u1F9F\u1FA8-\u1FAF\u1FBC\u1FCC\u1FFC]/g;
const toLowerMap = new Map([
  ['\u0130', 'i\u0307'],
  ['\u1F88', '\u1F80'],
  ['\u1F89', '\u1F81'],
  ['\u1F8A', '\u1F82'],
  ['\u1F8B', '\u1F83'],
  ['\u1F8C', '\u1F84'],
  ['\u1F8D', '\u1F85'],
  ['\u1F8E', '\u1F86'],
  ['\u1F8F', '\u1F87'],
  ['\u1F98', '\u1F90'],
  ['\u1F99', '\u1F91'],
  ['\u1F9A', '\u1F92'],
  ['\u1F9B', '\u1F93'],
  ['\u1F9C', '\u1F94'],
  ['\u1F9D', '\u1F95'],
  ['\u1F9E', '\u1F96'],
  ['\u1F9F', '\u1F97'],
  ['\u1FA8', '\u1FA0'],
  ['\u1FA9', '\u1FA1'],
  ['\u1FAA', '\u1FA2'],
  ['\u1FAB', '\u1FA3'],
  ['\u1FAC', '\u1FA4'],
  ['\u1FAD', '\u1FA5'],
  ['\u1FAE', '\u1FA6'],
  ['\u1FAF', '\u1FA7'],
  ['\u1FBC', '\u1FB3'],
  ['\u1FCC', '\u1FC3'],
  ['\u1FFC', '\u1FF3']
]);
const toLower = (string) => string.replace(reToLower, (match) => toLowerMap.get(match));

const reToUpper = /[\xDF\u0149\u01F0\u0390\u03B0\u0587\u1E96-\u1E9A\u1F50\u1F52\u1F54\u1F56\u1F80-\u1FAF\u1FB2-\u1FB4\u1FB6\u1FB7\u1FBC\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6\u1FC7\u1FCC\u1FD2\u1FD3\u1FD6\u1FD7\u1FE2-\u1FE4\u1FE6\u1FE7\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6\u1FF7\u1FFC\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17]/g;
const toUpperMap = new Map([
  ['\xDF', 'SS'],
  ['\uFB00', 'FF'],
  ['\uFB01', 'FI'],
  ['\uFB02', 'FL'],
  ['\uFB03', 'FFI'],
  ['\uFB04', 'FFL'],
  ['\uFB05', 'ST'],
  ['\uFB06', 'ST'],
  ['\u0587', '\u0535\u0552'],
  ['\uFB13', '\u0544\u0546'],
  ['\uFB14', '\u0544\u0535'],
  ['\uFB15', '\u0544\u053B'],
  ['\uFB16', '\u054E\u0546'],
  ['\uFB17', '\u0544\u053D'],
  ['\u0149', '\u02BCN'],
  ['\u0390', '\u0399\u0308\u0301'],
  ['\u03B0', '\u03A5\u0308\u0301'],
  ['\u01F0', 'J\u030C'],
  ['\u1E96', 'H\u0331'],
  ['\u1E97', 'T\u0308'],
  ['\u1E98', 'W\u030A'],
  ['\u1E99', 'Y\u030A'],
  ['\u1E9A', 'A\u02BE'],
  ['\u1F50', '\u03A5\u0313'],
  ['\u1F52', '\u03A5\u0313\u0300'],
  ['\u1F54', '\u03A5\u0313\u0301'],
  ['\u1F56', '\u03A5\u0313\u0342'],
  ['\u1FB6', '\u0391\u0342'],
  ['\u1FC6', '\u0397\u0342'],
  ['\u1FD2', '\u0399\u0308\u0300'],
  ['\u1FD3', '\u0399\u0308\u0301'],
  ['\u1FD6', '\u0399\u0342'],
  ['\u1FD7', '\u0399\u0308\u0342'],
  ['\u1FE2', '\u03A5\u0308\u0300'],
  ['\u1FE3', '\u03A5\u0308\u0301'],
  ['\u1FE4', '\u03A1\u0313'],
  ['\u1FE6', '\u03A5\u0342'],
  ['\u1FE7', '\u03A5\u0308\u0342'],
  ['\u1FF6', '\u03A9\u0342'],
  ['\u1F80', '\u1F08\u0399'],
  ['\u1F81', '\u1F09\u0399'],
  ['\u1F82', '\u1F0A\u0399'],
  ['\u1F83', '\u1F0B\u0399'],
  ['\u1F84', '\u1F0C\u0399'],
  ['\u1F85', '\u1F0D\u0399'],
  ['\u1F86', '\u1F0E\u0399'],
  ['\u1F87', '\u1F0F\u0399'],
  ['\u1F88', '\u1F08\u0399'],
  ['\u1F89', '\u1F09\u0399'],
  ['\u1F8A', '\u1F0A\u0399'],
  ['\u1F8B', '\u1F0B\u0399'],
  ['\u1F8C', '\u1F0C\u0399'],
  ['\u1F8D', '\u1F0D\u0399'],
  ['\u1F8E', '\u1F0E\u0399'],
  ['\u1F8F', '\u1F0F\u0399'],
  ['\u1F90', '\u1F28\u0399'],
  ['\u1F91', '\u1F29\u0399'],
  ['\u1F92', '\u1F2A\u0399'],
  ['\u1F93', '\u1F2B\u0399'],
  ['\u1F94', '\u1F2C\u0399'],
  ['\u1F95', '\u1F2D\u0399'],
  ['\u1F96', '\u1F2E\u0399'],
  ['\u1F97', '\u1F2F\u0399'],
  ['\u1F98', '\u1F28\u0399'],
  ['\u1F99', '\u1F29\u0399'],
  ['\u1F9A', '\u1F2A\u0399'],
  ['\u1F9B', '\u1F2B\u0399'],
  ['\u1F9C', '\u1F2C\u0399'],
  ['\u1F9D', '\u1F2D\u0399'],
  ['\u1F9E', '\u1F2E\u0399'],
  ['\u1F9F', '\u1F2F\u0399'],
  ['\u1FA0', '\u1F68\u0399'],
  ['\u1FA1', '\u1F69\u0399'],
  ['\u1FA2', '\u1F6A\u0399'],
  ['\u1FA3', '\u1F6B\u0399'],
  ['\u1FA4', '\u1F6C\u0399'],
  ['\u1FA5', '\u1F6D\u0399'],
  ['\u1FA6', '\u1F6E\u0399'],
  ['\u1FA7', '\u1F6F\u0399'],
  ['\u1FA8', '\u1F68\u0399'],
  ['\u1FA9', '\u1F69\u0399'],
  ['\u1FAA', '\u1F6A\u0399'],
  ['\u1FAB', '\u1F6B\u0399'],
  ['\u1FAC', '\u1F6C\u0399'],
  ['\u1FAD', '\u1F6D\u0399'],
  ['\u1FAE', '\u1F6E\u0399'],
  ['\u1FAF', '\u1F6F\u0399'],
  ['\u1FB3', '\u0391\u0399'],
  ['\u1FBC', '\u0391\u0399'],
  ['\u1FC3', '\u0397\u0399'],
  ['\u1FCC', '\u0397\u0399'],
  ['\u1FF3', '\u03A9\u0399'],
  ['\u1FFC', '\u03A9\u0399'],
  ['\u1FB2', '\u1FBA\u0399'],
  ['\u1FB4', '\u0386\u0399'],
  ['\u1FC2', '\u1FCA\u0399'],
  ['\u1FC4', '\u0389\u0399'],
  ['\u1FF2', '\u1FFA\u0399'],
  ['\u1FF4', '\u038F\u0399'],
  ['\u1FB7', '\u0391\u0342\u0399'],
  ['\u1FC7', '\u0397\u0342\u0399'],
  ['\u1FF7', '\u03A9\u0342\u0399']
]);
const toUpper = (string) => string.replace(reToUpper, (match) => toUpperMap.get(match));
```