# Checking if any documents in Firestore contain a substring

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a pretty large collection of documents in Firestore with random IDs and each one of those documents has two fields, a name and a description. I want my app to allow the user to enter a series of characters and then present to him all the documents which contain that sequence of chars in let's say the name field. Is this feasible using Firebase & its queries and if so, could you give me a code example in Kotlin or Java? I know there are some methods such as `hasChild()` or `child("child name").exists()` but since i don't yet know which document the user is looking for i can't use them if i'm not mistaken.

For example, if i had a collection of 3 documents which had the following names ("mike","michael","dave") and the user entered "mi", i'd like to be able to retrieve the documents whose names are "mike" & "michael".

Comment: Are you using Realtime Database or firestore?

Comment: I'm using Firestore, i'm gonna add that to my post

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail There is a little "hack" that can be made in Firestore than can help you [search the database easier](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to get all documents where the `name` field starts with `mi`, you can do so with:

```
db.collection("users")
  .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("name", "mi")
  .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("name", "mi\uF7FF")
  .get()
  .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
    for (document in documents) {
      Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
    }
  }
    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
    }
```

The `\uF7FF` value used here is the last Unicode character that exists, so this:

1. Orders all documents by their `name` value
2. Finds the first document that starts with `mi`
3. returns all documents, until it reaches one that's bigger than `mi`

For much more on this, read the Firebase documentation on [querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

I also recommend checking out these related questions:

- [Google Firestore: Query on substring of a property value (text search)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568142/google-firestore-query-on-substring-of-a-property-value-text-search)
- [Cloud Firestore Case Insensitive Sorting Using Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096063/cloud-firestore-case-insensitive-sorting-using-query/48098215#48098215)

Comment: Where can I find the API docs for `whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo()` ?

Comment: Ah, found it.  Surprisingly it did not show up in a google search for "firestore whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo".  But it is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)