# Firebase text search with startAt and endAt doesn't work incase sensitive

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make search field in my app, I am using startAt and endAt methods. These methods work very well without case sensitivity. But, unfortunately it doesn't work properly with incase sensitivity.

```
   let startText = searchText.toUpperCase();
   let endText = searchText.toLowerCase()
  
   const productRef=db
      .collection("products")
      .orderBy(searchField)
      .startAt(startText).endAt(endText+"\uf8ff");
```

Assume I have **["a", "A", "AB", "ABC", "Z", "a"]**
If I search **"AB"** it only sorts the data only, it retrieves **"AB", "ABC", "Z", "a"**
Or if I search **"z"** it retrieves **"Z", "a", "z"**

Am I doing something wrong or this method actually doesn't work?

I have seen people keeping lowercase versions of fields in the document, is this the only way of solving the problem?

name:"Overflow"
nameLower:"overflow"

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Searches in Firestore are case sensitive. What you found is the idiomatic workaround. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096063/cloud-firestore-case-insensitive-sorting-using-query