# Firestore Query Not Returning Data Based on searchText

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uisearchbar

My searchBar text is updating my query, but not returning the data from Firestore as I would expect.

This is the method in my data model:

```
func getMealPlans(starred starredOnly:Bool = false, textToQuery searchText:String = "") {
        
        listener?.remove()

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        var query:Query = db.collection("mealPlans")
           
        query = query.whereField("title", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchText)
        
        func queryData() {
            
            self.listener = query.addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
                
                // Check for errors
                if error == nil && snapshot != nil {
                    
                    var mealPlans = [MealPlan]()
                    
                    // Parse documents into mealPlans
                    for doc in snapshot!.documents {
                        
                        let m = MealPlan(
                            docID: doc["docID"] as? String,
                            title: doc["title"] as! String)
                        
                        mealPlans.append(m)
                    }
                    // Call the delegate and pass back the notes in the main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.delegate?.mealPlansRetrieved(mealPlans: mealPlans)
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        queryData()   
    }
```

And this is my search bar method in my view controller:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        let searchedText = searchText.lowercased()
        model.getMealPlans(textToQuery: searchedText)
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I'm wondering if `query = query.whereField("title", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchText)` in my model might be the root of my issue. When I `print(searchText)` after this code, the `searchText` that I type shows up in the console as expected. But the table view doesn't update with the cells that have a *matching* `title`, even if it's an *exact* match.

Answer (score 0):

```
 You need to use document data property to load MealPlan. Better make it the following way:
    
    1. Define data model as Codable:

import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
            
struct MealPlan: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    title: String?
}

2. Then use compact map to get mealPlans:

mealPlans = snapshot.documents.compactMap { document -> MealPlan? in
     do {
         let result = try document.data(as: MealPlan.self)
         return result
     }
     catch {
         print(error)
         return nil
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue ended up being rooted in my database containing proper case values, whereas my queries were all lowercase. Apparently it's [recommended to store my searchable data in its own key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096063/cloud-firestore-case-insensitive-sorting-using-query), so I created a keywords array for my data to be searched.

My query then became:
`query = query.whereField("keywords", arrayContains: searchText)`