# How to make search non-case-sensitive

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i have a collection with name user and doc with doc id 'dos12'

and have data like this
({
number:2322012,
name:'abc
})

i am using

```
firestore().collection('user').orderBy('name')
            .startAt('abc)
            .endAt('abc + '\uf8ff')
.get()
```

This is case sensitive if i am searching Abc then it is not getting results. How can i make it non-case Sensitive so that i can get on search abc or ABC get same results. As well as how can make it if i search a letter b letter or c letter then also get results. Now if i search bc then not getting any result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To support case-insensitive, you'll need to write a separate field like

```
db.collection("users").where("name", "==", "Abc")
db.collection("users").where("name_lowercase", "==", "abc")
```

Something similar to the following

```
firestore().collection('user').orderBy('username_lowercase')
    .startAt(username.toLowerCase())
   .endAt(username.toLowerCase() + "\uf8ff")
```

For Ref: [Firestore-queries-still-case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554793/are-cloud-firestore-queries-still-case-sensitive) and [firestore-case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096063/cloud-firestore-case-insensitive-sorting-using-query/48098215#48098215)

Comment: i tried with the firestore().collection('user').orderBy('username_lowercase')
    .startAt(username.toLowerCase())
   .endAt(username.toLowerCase() + "\uf8ff") but this is not working if i am searching ABC it just giving me data for ABC only